# How to remove certain entries of context menu [(...)-Menu] using Script Editor Web Part (JavaScript, jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, script

How can I remove certain entries of the context menu (marked in my screenshot with red border) by using **Script Editor Web Part**? As an example, I would like to remove the entries "Im Browser bearbeiten" and "Konformitätsdetails".

[image]

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do, is to override the function in Core.js on the current page instead. If its a library the actions are added in the AddDocLibMenuItems. And the View/Edit Properties are added from the AddShareNamespaceMenuItems function. So you could add this function to your page, just make sure its loaded after Core.js:

```
function AddDocLibMenuItems(m, ctxt) {
    if (typeof window.Custom_AddDocLibMenuItems != "undefined") {
        if (window.Custom_AddDocLibMenuItems(m, ctxt))
            return;
    }
    var RootFolder = GetRootFolder(ctxt);
    var menuOption;
    var strDisplayText;
    var strAction;
    var strImagePath;

    //AddSharedNamespaceMenuItems(m, ctxt);
    var currentItemEscapedFileUrl;

    if (currentItemFileUrl != null)
        currentItemEscapedFileUrl = escapeProperly(unescapeProperly(currentItemFileUrl));
    var serverFileRedirect = itemTable.getAttribute("SRed");
    var systemCheckout = currentItemCheckedOutUserId == String(SYSTEM_ACCOUNT_ID) && ctxt.CurrentUserId != String(SYSTEM_ACCOUNT_ID);

    if (HasRights(0x0, 0x4) && HasRights(0x10, 0x0) && !systemCheckout && (serverFileRedirect == null || serverFileRedirect == "" || HasRights(0x0, 0x20))) {
        if (ctxt.isWebEditorPreview == 0 && ctxt.listBaseType == 1) {
            if (ctxt.listTemplate != 119) {
                setDocType();
                if (currentItemAppName != "" && currentItemOpenControl != "") {
                    if (!(ctxt.IsAppWeb && currentItemProgId == SPDesignerProgID)) {
                        strDisplayText = "";
                        if (currentItemAppName != " ")
                            strDisplayText = StBuildParam(Strings.STS.L_EditIn_Text, currentItemAppName);
                        else {
                            var objEditor = StsOpenEnsureEx2(currentItemOpenControl + ".3");

                            if (objEditor != null)
                                strDisplayText = Strings.STS.L_EditInApplication_Text;
                        }
                        if (strDisplayText != "") {
                            strAction = "editDocumentWithProgID2('" + currentItemFileUrl + "', '" + currentItemProgId + "', '" + currentItemOpenControl + "', '" + String(bIsCheckout) + "', '" + ctxt.HttpRoot + "', '" + currentItemCheckedoutToLocal + "', '" + currentItemOpenApp + "')";
                            strImagePath = ctxt.imagesPath + currentItemIcon;
                            menuOption = CAMOpt(m, strDisplayText, strAction, strImagePath, null, String(260));
                            menuOption.id = "ID_EditIn_" + currentItemAppName;
                            menuOption.style.cssText = "display:none";
                            CUIInfo(menuOption, "EditDocument", ["EditDocument"]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    CAMSep(m);
    if (HasRights(0x0, 0x4)) {
        if (currentItemFSObjType != "1") {
            if (ctxt.listBaseType == 1) {
                AddCheckinCheckoutMenuItem(m, ctxt, currentItemEscapedFileUrl);
            }
        }
    }
    if ((ctxt.verEnabled == 1 || ctxt.isModerated) && currentItemFSObjType != "1") {
        AddVersionsMenuItem(m, ctxt, currentItemEscapedFileUrl);
    }
    if (HasRights(0x0, 0x4)) {
        if (ctxt.isModerated == true && HasRights(0x0, 0x10) && ((currentItemModerationStatus == String(2) || !ctxt.EnableMinorVersions) && currentItemCheckedOutUserId == "" || currentItemFSObjType == "1")) {
            strDisplayText = Strings.STS.L_ModerateItem_Text;
            strAction = "NavigateToApproveRejectAspx(event, '" + ctxt.HttpRoot + "/_layouts/15/approve.aspx?List=" + ctxt.listName + "&ID=" + currentItemID;
            strAction = AddSourceToUrl(strAction) + GetRootFolder(ctxt) + "')";
            strImagePath = ctxt.imagesPath + "apprj.gif";
            menuOption = CAMOpt(m, strDisplayText, strAction, strImagePath, null, String(850));
            CUIInfo(menuOption, "Moderate", ["Moderate"]);
            menuOption.id = "ID_ModerateItem";
        }
    }
    CAMSep(m);
    AddWorkflowsMenuItem(m, ctxt);
    if (currentItemFSObjType != "1") {
        if (ctxt.PortalUrl != null) {
            strDisplayText = Strings.STS.L_AddToMyLinks_Text;
            strAction = "Portal_Tasks('PinToMyPage')";
            ;
            strImagePath = "";
            menuOption = CAMOpt(m, strDisplayText, strAction, strImagePath, null, String(1000));
            CUIInfo(menuOption, "AddToMyLinks", ["AddToMyLinks"]);
            menuOption.id = "ID_AddToMyLinks";
            menuOption.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    else if (ctxt.listBaseType == 1 && HasRights(0x10, 0x0)) {
        AddWorkOfflineMenuItem(m, ctxt, currentItemFileUrl);
    }
    if (HasRights(0x80, 0x0) && typeof _spPageContextInfo != 'undefined' && _spPageContextInfo != null && typeof _spPageContextInfo.alertsEnabled == 'boolean' && _spPageContextInfo.alertsEnabled) {
        strDisplayText = Strings.STS.L_Subscribe_Text;
        strAction = "NavigateToSubNewAspxV4(event, '" + ctxt.HttpRoot + "', 'List=" + ctxt.listName + "&ID=" + currentItemID + "')";
        strImagePath = "";
        menuOption = CAMOpt(m, strDisplayText, strAction, strImagePath, null, String(1100));
        CUIInfo(menuOption, "Subscribe", ["Subscribe"]);
        menuOption.id = "ID_Subscribe";
        menuOption.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (currentItemFSObjType != "1") {
        AddSendSubMenu(m, ctxt);
        AddGotoSourceItemMenuItem(m, ctxt, itemTable, currentItemFSObjType);
        AddDocTransformSubMenu(m, ctxt);
    }
    CAMSep(m);
    AddManagePermsMenuItem(m, ctxt, ctxt.listName, currentItemID);
    if (HasRights(0x0, 0x8) && !systemCheckout) {
        strDisplayText = Strings.STS.L_DeleteDocItem_Text;
        var isCopy = "false";

        if (typeof itemTable.getAttribute("CSrc") != "undefined" && itemTable.getAttribute("CSrc") != null && itemTable.getAttribute("CSrc") != "") {
            isCopy = "true";
        }
        strAction = "DeleteDocLibItem('" + ctxt.HttpPath + "&Cmd=Delete&List=" + ctxt.listName + "&ID=" + currentItemID + "&owsfileref=" + currentItemEscapedFileUrl + "&NextUsing=" + GetSource() + "'," + isCopy + ")";
        strImagePath = ctxt.imagesPath + "delitem.gif";
        menuOption = CAMOpt(m, strDisplayText, strAction, strImagePath, null, String(1190));
        menuOption.id = "ID_DeleteDocItem";
        CUIInfo(menuOption, "Delete", ["Delete"]);
    }
    if (HasRights(0x0, 0x4) && currentItemFSObjType == "1" && ctxt.ContentTypesEnabled && ctxt.listTemplate != 108) {
        strDisplayText = Strings.STS.L_CustomizeNewButton_Text;
        strAction = "STSNavigate('" + ctxt.HttpRoot + "/_layouts/15/ChangeContentTypeOrder.aspx?List=" + ctxt.listName + "&RootFolder=" + currentItemEscapedFileUrl;
        strAction = AddSourceToUrl(strAction) + "')";
        strImagePath = "";
        menuOption = CAMOpt(m, strDisplayText, strAction, strImagePath, null, String(1170));
        CUIInfo(menuOption, "ChangeNewButton", ["ChangeNewButton"]);
        menuOption.id = "ID_CustomizeNewButton";
    }
}
```

Simply use this

```
<style> li.ms-core-menu-item[text="TEXT(of the entry which should be hidden)"] { display: none !important; } </style>
```

Please refer the[Link for Source](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/114587/remove-item-from-ecb-in-sharepoint-2013)

Comment: Thank you. Your link for source brought me to the page, where I found a code for CSS which works. I just embed following CSS to Script Editor Web Part:
<style>
li.ms-core-menu-item[text="TEXT(of the entry which should be hidden)"] {
    display: none !important;
}
</style>

Comment: You are welcome. Happy Coding!!!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do it, is to add this CSS to a Script Editor:

```
<style> li.ms-core-menu-item[text="TEXT(of the entry which should be hidden)"] { display: none !important; } </style>
```